# Meson can't find cmake subdirectory

Tags: meson-build, subproject

In one of my `meson.build` files, I have code that I need to generate a dependency for spdlog.

```
libspd = cmake.subproject('spdlog')
spd_dep = libspd.dependency('spd_dep')
```

The `meson.build` in question resides in a directory called `vendor`, and the spdlog directory also sits in it.

```
./
  ...
  vendor/
    meson.build
    spdlog/
      CMakeLists.txt
      ...
```

However, when I configure the project, meson throws this error:
`Neither a subproject directory nor a spdlog.wrap file was found.`. Why is this? Clearly, the spdlog directory is in the same directory as in `meson.build` in question, right?

Also, I know I should be using wrapfiles, but due to limitations that is impossible. I've also asked on IRC, but no-one responded, and I'm on a deadline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meson has predefined location for subprojects - *[All subprojects must be in subprojects directory](https://mesonbuild.com/Subprojects.html#using-a-subproject)*.  So, you should have structure:

```
  vendor/
    meson.build
    subprojects/
      spdlog/
        CMakeLists.txt
```